# UIScrollView and UINavigationController not working with iOS 4

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview

i have a problem with UIScrollView and UINavigationController(s) and iOS 4. The following code works fine with iOS 5:

```
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /* Scroll View */ 
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 mScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 88, 1024, 668)];
 mScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1850, 668);

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // First View 
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:           @"view_bg.png"]];
 imgView.frame= CGRectMake(10, 50, 350, 510);
 [mScrollView addSubview:imgView];
 [imgView release];

 mFirstView = [[[FirstView alloc]  init] autorelease];
 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mFirstView]; 
 navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:79.0/255 green:143.0/255 blue:0.0/255 alpha:1];
 navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(25, 65, 320, 480);   
 [mScrollView addSubview:navigationController.view];

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Second View
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 UIImageView *imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"view_bg.png"]];
 imgView2.frame= CGRectMake(380, 50, 350, 510);
 [mScrollView addSubview:imgView2];
 [imgView2 release];

 mSecondView = [[[SecondView alloc]  init] autorelease];
 UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mSecondView]; 
 navigationController2.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:79.0/255     green:143.0/255 blue:0.0/255 alpha:1];
 navigationController2.view.frame = CGRectMake(395, 65, 320, 480);
[mScrollView addSubview:navigationController2.view];

// finally add the scroll view to the parent view
[self.view addSubview:mScrollView];
```

All i do is, to add a ScrollView with 2 NavigationControllers (with a allocated root view controller) do the view. But using this code with iOS 4 does not show the right size of the ViewControllers added. The ViewControllers are the size of the whole iPad screen!!!!!

As i already said, it works on iOS 5! Even when i change the size of the views added manually it is not working, the added view always fills the whole iPad screen!! Any ideas to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have the following

```
//first view you add mfirstview.view
[mScrollView addSubview:mFirstView.view];

//second view you add navigationController2.view
[mScrollView addSubview: navigationController2.view];
```

So i guess you have to change the first view code to do the following

```
[mScrollView addSubview: navigationController.view];
```

Comment: oh sorry .. this was a typo!! i changed the original class names from my code ...  i edited my posting above!